# Images showing as not found while they exist on the server

Tags: html, image, web, hosting, cpanel

I'm having a site with 2 images that exist on the server but shows as not found to go to the site.

Everything works fine in my local computer. But when I upload the site to the host, the images break.

I tried changing the image name and the img src target and it worked.
However when I changed to back the original image file name, the image appears as not found again.

The image file name is dthotels.gif. It works when I changed to Dthotels.gif or 1dthotels.gif

Why does image file name affect the visibility of the image?

Thank you

Comment: Needs way more info. What does the name look like that doesn't work, and what does the one look like that does work?

Comment: The image file name is dthotels.gif. It works when I changed to Dthotels.gif or 1dthotels.gif

Comment: Everything works fine in my local computer. But when I upload the site to the host, the images break.

Answer (score -1):

Linux is case-sensitive while Windows isn't so maybe your remote server is linux based and your local machine is Windows. That's a common issue.

Keep your file name lowercase and you should be fine!

Comment: Thank you. But the original file names are all in lower case. Just changing the filename to anything different makes it work, not necessary changing the case. For example, I added "1" the filename and the image can display fine.

Comment: Ricardo, that doesn't provide any relevant info. That's well known by user3141778 as you can see from his question and his explanation.